# change icon color based on value of SQL table in flask

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask

I use .py code to show table in html:

```
@flask.route('/users_table', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def users_table():
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE isadmin = 0')
    all_users = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('users-table.html', all_users=all_users
```

and .html code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Tools</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
      {% for row in all_users %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{row.username}}</td>
        <td>{{row.email}}</td>
        <td>{{row.company_name}}</td>
        <td>{{row.isenabled}}</td>
        <td><a href="/reset_user_pass/{{row.Id}}" data-toggle="modal" data- 
        target="#modaledit{{row.Id}}"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

[show sql table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtZrr.png)

I want to change 'fa fa-play' icon based on value on 'status' column.

How can i achieve that

Comment: Which icon do you want for which status?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use conditional statements.

```
<td><a href="/reset_user_pass/{{row.Id}}" data-toggle="modal" data- 
        target="#modaledit{{row.Id}}"> 
{% if row.status == 0  %}
    <i class="fa fa-play"></i></a> 
{% else %}
    <i class="SOMETHING ELSE"></i></a>
{% endif %}
</td>
```

You can also checkout ternary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
<i class="fa fa-{{ 'icon1' if row.isenabled else 'icon2' }}"></i>
```

Assuming that status value is determined based on `row.isenabled`, you can use inline `if/else` to show different icons as per the condition. I have used `icon1` and `icon2` which you can replace with real icons.